# Magento 2 - Weird behavior during checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I developed a Magento2 webshop with a custom theme and some extensions. Now suddenly, the checkout page shows weird behavior.

When I go to /checkout I see the spinner indicating that the Magento is building the checkout page. But, then I only see the email field and the coupon box. All other steps and fields are there, but they are hidden by the steps js I think.

The Payment step is directly shown instead of the billing address step.

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on here?

You can find the store here: [goo.gl/QLG3A](http://goo.gl/QLG3AS)S (Dutch)

### Update

The problem only seems to happen when (only) a configurable product is added to the cart, for example: goo.gl/gB30Bd. But if I add a simple product, for example: goo.gl/3vrCRX (alone, or with a configurable product) the checkout seem to work just fine.

Comment: Magento 2's checkout is significantly reworked and streamlined. Did you try entering your email address?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I enter an email that has an account than the password field pop's up. I the email is unknown nothing happens and I cannot continue.

Comment: Have you checked browser console? It might show some JS failing to load, for example.

Comment: Yes, I did. But, there's no error at all...

Comment: Have you tried disabling the modules and seeing if the issue still persists? Also, do any of the modules affect the checkout?

Comment: Yes I did. If I disable all modules nothing changes. If I try to switch themes I get a white page on every page (also weird?).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying place order and successful do it. So, looks like problem in browser cache. Please try clean cache or do the checkout in incognito mode. Also please enable static file sign to do not have problem with cached content.

Comment: It occurs sometimes, I do have it right at this moment. Could you check again? I think you'll have the problem too.

Comment: I've updated my question, maybe you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you verify, maybe product assigned to configurable have virtual type?

Comment: The products assigned to the configurable product do have virtual type. Is this wrong?

Comment: It's normal. But in this scenario where product is not shippable the first step where user enter shipping information will be skipped.